# image checkbox form with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to make a checkbox form that has mouse over image and checked image function with jquery.

I successfully made the function but didn't work good enough.

here is my html form.

```
<label for="w_interest">
    <img src="/images/account/w_select.png_img"/ style='cursor:pointer;'>
    <input name="w_interest" type="checkbox" id="w_interest" style="display:none">
</label>
```

here is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#img').hover(
     function () {
         $(this).attr('src', '/images/account/ws_145_hover.png');
      },
     function () {
         $(this).attr('src', '/images/account/ws_145.png');
      }
  );

  $("#img").click(function() {
     if(1) {
         $(this).attr("src", "/images/account/ws_145_checked.png");
         $("#w_interest").val("0");
     } else {
         $(this).attr("src", "/images/account/ws_145.png");
         $("#w_interest").val("1");
     }
  });
});
```

1. It changes to checked image when I click the image. However, when I move the mouse out, it change to the original image. I wanna make sure that it stays to checked image.
2. I would like to make sure that it checks the checkbox input.
3. If a user click the checked image again, it deselects checkbox input.

Can you help me to fix jquery to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/tErvQ/

Code:

```
$('.imag_box img').hover(
     function () {
         if($(this).next().val() !== "1") {
             $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/150/000000/fbaf5d');
         }
      },
     function () {
         if($(this).next().val() !== "1") {
             $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/150/000000/ffffff');
         }
     }
  );


$(".imag_box img").click(function() {
    if($(this).next().val() !== "1") {
         $(this).attr("src", "http://placehold.it/150/000000/00ff18");
         $(this).next().val("1");
    } else {
         $(this).attr("src", "http://placehold.it/150/000000/ffffff");
         $(this).next().val("0");
    }
});
```

Hope that's what you needed :)

It might be a better idea to use the attribute checked instead, since if you are submitting the form, it might be handled better in the post.

Answer (score 0):

is it typo if(1){

i think you should be comparing with the

```
if($("#w_interest").val() == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = [
        '/images/account/ws_145.png',
        '/images/account/ws_145_hover.png'
    ];
    var $w_interest = $("#w_interest");
    var $img = $('#img');
    $img.hover(function () {
        $img.attr('src', images[1]);
    }, function () {
        if($w_interest.val() == "0") {
            $img.attr("src", images[0]);
        }
    });

    $img.click(function() {
        if($w_interest.val() == "1") {
            $img.attr("src", images[0]);
            $w_interest.val("0");
        } else {
            $img.attr("src", images[1]);
            $w_interest.val("1");
        }
    });
});
```